# How to merge 2 tasks contents into one in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, devops

There are 2 tasks under the same work item. The tasks need to be merged into one.
How to do this in Azure DevOps

Comment: Manually. I don't think there is a "merge" feature in Azure DevOps.

Comment: Manually copy the content form one task to others?

Comment: Yes... And delete one task after it.

Comment: @user1254579, Hi, how the things going? Does the below script sample could help you merge tasks successfully now? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave commend here thus I could continue to help you:-)

Comment: @user1254579 Did you try out Frank's solution? Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps doesn't have the feature that can merge work items. So you should manually copy the content from one task to another.
Or you can use REST API to get the contents from one work item and then add the useful contents to another one.
Here is the REST API to get single work item.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workitemId}?api-version=5.1
```

Here is the REST API to update the specific work item.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workitemId}?api-version=5.1
```

Here is the request body when you update the work item.

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "Hyperlink",
      "url": "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/05/12/a-new-api-for-visual-studio-online.aspx"
    }
  }
]
```

More detail information about the parameters `op`, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples